# How to extract the 'Cost Center ID' of the current user from Delve using Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

How to get "Cost Center ID" from Delve in Power Apps for current login user

I'm trying following formula

`Set(varcost,Office365Users.UserProfileV2(User().Email).interests)`

I'm able to fetch the interests but not the "Cost Center ID" present in Additional Information section in Delve.

Please let me know how to fetch "Cost Center ID" from Delve for current login user in power apps

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a Delve connector in the Power Platform currently supported by Microsoft. Here is a helpful resource where you can look up all of the current supported Power Platform API connectors and their constraints (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/). I even took a look into the Microsoft Graph API and couldn't find anything. Here is that link if you are curious. (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).